# Bootstrap 3.3.7 Navbar toggle button not seem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

When I shrink the window and there is no toggle button on screen. But pointer change like it is button.

I read all forum and applied many solutions but nothing change.

My css : bootstrap 3.3.7 min.css
my js  :  bootstrap min.js & jquery.min.js 3.2.0

Here is my header.html template:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Navbar Start -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Telefon ekranları için menü butonu -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Menü</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- İsim Soyisim veya Marka İsmi -->
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="navbar-brand">Bu Kim Lan</a>
            </div>



            <!--<img src="static\img\qm8.ico" alt="Anasayfa" width=20" height="20" >-->

            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">

                <!-- Arama Çubuğu -->
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="GET" action="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Başlıkta Ara" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" >
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Ara">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>


                <!-- Temel Sayfalar -->
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">



                        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Anasayfa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'post:create' %}">Gönder Gelsin</a></li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>-->
                        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'post:index' %}">TT</a></li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Üye Ol</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Giriş Yap</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Çıkış</a></li>
                        {% endif %}

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. you lost *navbar-default* on **class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default"**(line 1)
2. your *data-target="#navbar"* should be target to **nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar" role="navigation"**(line 26)

Please check below links:

[Official Sample](https://getbootstrap)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="navbar-brand">Bu Kim Lan</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Anasayfa</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'post:create' %}">Gönder Gelsin</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>-->

        <li><a href="{% url 'post:index' %}">TT</a></li>

        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Üye Ol</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Giriş Yap</a></li>

        <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Çıkış</a></li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="GET" action="">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Başlıkta Ara" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Ara">
                        </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. Yes Toggle bar seem but function is not useful. When I click the toggle, I can not see the menu. And other issue is colour changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HaşimUyanık 1.Toggle function will run, if you minimize the window size. 2.Every navbar item should contain in <a> (note: I updated code upper.)